# How do I fix the delay and lagging when running the program through an EXE?

Tags: python, exe, live-update

I am working on a sensor reading program where part of the program involves printing out live updates of the sensor's status when the metal target moves further or closer to the sensor. The "main_gui.py" file will be the first to run, and once user clicks the button "Start Data Retrieval", it will start the subprocess "IES2V2.py" where it does the sensor reading process and prints out.

The code below shows how the code, originally printing in the console, will be printed into the GUI instead.

```
    def start_data_retrieval(self):
        # Start a new thread for data retrieval
        threading.Thread(target=self.retrieve_data_thread).start()

    def retrieve_data_thread(self):
        selected_current = LoadCurrent[currentgrp.get()]
        selected_output = OutputType[outputgrp.get()]
        print(f"Selected Current: {selected_current}, Selected Output: {selected_output}")

        with subprocess.Popen(["python", "IES2V2.py", "--port", self._port, "--current", selected_current.name, "--output", selected_output.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as process:
            for line in process.stdout:
                line = line.decode()  # defaulting to system encoding
                text_box.insert(END, line)
                text_box.update()
                text_box.see(END)
                process.poll()
```

When running the EXE, I faced delays when printing out of the statements onto GUI once "Start Data Retrieval" button is clicked, the printing data will come out as a huge chunk of data in a rush and have a long delay before printing again. I expected it to run smoothly like in PyCharm...

Note: I also faced issues when creating the EXE, having errors like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VUKR.png). I fixed it by copying the files it couldn't find into the path and the EXE runs ok from my side. Just an fyi in case this could be the cause of the delay...but i think it shouldn't be.

Edit: IES2V2.py code(some of it) Below is the part where it reads the sensor output and updates continuously.

```
print('\n---- Reading Data ----')
print("Live update of sensor data PROCESS_ADDR will begin. Press the 'Enter' key to stop the updates.")
time.sleep(5)

prev_process_addr = ies2.get_value(122)
while True:
    print(f'Update of PROCESS_ADDR : {ies2.get_value(122)}')  # SU
    new_process_addr = ies2.get_value(122)
    if new_process_addr != prev_process_addr:
        print(f"PROCESS_ADDR value changed! {prev_process_addr} to {new_process_addr}")
        prev_process_addr = new_process_addr

    if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
     print("\nKey pressed! Stopping the sensor updates.")
     break
```

Comment: You forgot to give lots of important details, like the source code of `IES2V2.py`, but I would guess this is a simple case of forgetting to flush data after it's written to the standard output.

Comment: I added '''process.stdout.flush() ''' in my code but the problem still exists. I have edited to add code for IES2V2 :)

Comment: You still haven't posted your full code, and there  is a 5-second sleep command in it, and there is no flushing in what you posted.

Comment: Hi, I am not able to post all the code, but the code i added in my edit is part of the lagging. Regarding the flushing, i attempted it this way:
with subprocess.Popen(["...... --output", selected_output.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, bufsize=1, text=True) as process:
        for line in process.stdout:
            line = line.decode()  # defaulting to system encoding
            text_box.insert(END, line)
            text_box.update()
            text_box.see(END)
            process.stdout.flush()  
        process.poll()

Comment: Flushing from the parent process won't do anything because you aren't using the parent process's stdout for anything.  You are using the child process's stdout to send data to the parent, so the child process has to flush its own stdout buffer after each attempt to send data.  Look up the documentation of print and it's arguments.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your help and patience. I looked up the documentation of print and added flush in the print statements in the child process, and it works! The EXE does not lack when printing the output now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discovered in the comments, the child process was not flushing its standard output buffer, which is what caused the delay.  One way to flush the standard output is to add `flush=True` when you call the `print` function.